# The meaning of "happy he is"

Tags: meaning

Consider:

> Actually, I can't even remember why I married him. Look at the state of him. Smiling away to himself. The great big eejit. **Happy he is**. The fucking nerve. He's no right to be happy when I feel like a bag of shit.*

Source: Catherine Barry: "The Twenty-Eights Day". In Irish Girls About Town, 2004, p. 39.

Is it usual in English to have a structure of the kind *Happy he is*? Where the adjective is in the very beginning of the sentence. I understand it as if the author/character omitted some words; so the full version would be "Look at him how happy he is". Am I right or is the matter in a different way?

Comment: Does the subject of happiness arise in sentences preceding the ones you've quoted?  The inversion can mean different things. For example, we can say "I warned you, you might fall, and fall you did."  to say "And damn, if I wasn't right about that! I told you so!"  Or it could mean "If I had to put a word to that look on his face, I'd say he was "happy".  It really depends on the context. Or it could mean "*he* may be happy, but I am not."

Comment: Yes, he does. But only as an object of hate of the woman that narrates the story.

Comment: I do not understand your comment.  What do you mean "he does"? That "he mentions happiness"?

Comment: I meant that the man was mentioned in the preceeding passages. Not the very fact of his happiness.

Comment: This kind of inversion is not usual in most varieties of English. I think it is more common in varieties that have been influenced by Celtic languages such as Irish and Welsh. I assume that the author of your extract is Irish (and the word "eejit" confirms this).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means nothing more or less than "He is happy." It's just an example of [inversion](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/inversion): writing the subject before the object, as we do in questions but also sometimes just for variety. It's not a common construction but it's not super-rare.

This is a construction that Yoda might use, though that's not what the author is aiming at. No words have actually been omitted but the closest sentence with essentially the same meaning would be something like "Happy – that's what he is."

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to understand what it is that admits the inversion, it would be "Look at the state of him".

> Look at the state of him: Happy he is.

"Smiling away to himself. The great big eejit" is actually a parenthetic.

> Look at the state of him—smiling away to himself, the great big eejit—happy he is.

The word "happy" moved to the front of the clause is positioned as the continuation of that invitation to look at the state of him, smiling eejit that he is; that he is happy is what one will see when beholding the state of him.

"Happy" is "the state".